# How to apply a filter to an ACF wysiwig editor field output?

Tags: filters, advanced-custom-fields

i have a filter to change the content on a plugin:

```
add_filter('the_content','replace_content');
```

Now i am using ACF and i copied over the content from the wordpress editor to a **wysiwig editor field** my filter doesn't affect it anymore.

So my question is how can i modify my filter to affect my new wysiwig custom field?

I am refering to the front end not the editor itself but the content people sees on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
add_filter('acf_the_content', 'replace_content');
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice

Comment: The filter he's using just affect Wordpress' default wysiwig. To do the same on ACF's wysiwig he needs to use the filter above.

Comment: Wow this worked thanks!. Is there an easy way to affect both without duplicating the function with a different name?

Comment: You don't need to duplicate de function, just call it on both filters.